# node-jslint with Syntastic in vim on Cygwin only display partial errors

Tags: vim, cygwin, jslint, syntastic

On win7, I have installed Cygwin, and installed [node-jslint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jslint) by

```
npm install -g jslint
```

And node-jslint will be my Javascript syntax checker in [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) by configuring in .vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_js_checkers=['jslint']
```

I have a file `test.js` with only one line of code:

```
function(){console.log('hello')}
```

While in `cmd.exe`, running `jslint test.js` I get:

```
test.js
#1 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    function(){console.log('hello')} // Line 1, Pos 9
#2 Missing name in function statement.
    function(){console.log('hello')} // Line 1, Pos 9
#3 Stopping. (50% scanned).
    // Line 1, Pos 9
```

But in Cygwin, running the same command I instead get:

```
test.js
```

It seems that some output has been cut by Cygwin due to some issues.

In vim, while running **Syntastic** checker for js-filetype files, I only get **some of the** errors but never get all of them like I run in `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 1):

By default syntastic passes a number of options to `jslint`, namely `--white --nomen --regexp --plusplus --bitwise --newcap --sloppy --vars`.  You can override this list by setting `g:syntastic_javascript_jslint_args` to your own list of options, f.i.:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_jslint_args` = "--white"
```

Setting said variable to the empty string `""` to run `jslint` without options is also valid.